# Overhead for not simplifying names in C#

Tags: c#

I am working with a C# windows forms application (I doubt the project type affects answer but there it is anyways) and everything is going good. Code works fine. However Visual studio likes to tell me that `Name can be simplified' when I do things like like using`this`in some methods where the`this` may not be needed. Here is an example:

```
public class xyz
{
    string startdate;

    string enddate;

    private void calculateElapsedTime()
    {
        var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.enddate).ToUniversalTime();
        var startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.startdate).ToUniversalTime();
        elapsedtime = (decimal)(endDate - startDate).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

The names that can be simplified are `this.startdate`and `this.enddate`

The code runs fine without the `this` keyword but personally I like using the 'this' as for me it makes it more clear what is being done.

I tried running tests on memory usage and time if I go through and simplify all places where VS says I should and I ran the same test without simplifying names and got the same results.

So this has lead me to the question, Is there any actual performance hit for not simplifying names or is the hit so small that I just don't see the difference because my program isn't big enough or some third option?

**EDIT** 
Since this is starting to get into a discussion on naming conventions figured I would add this. The above is a just an example of code that has a name that can be simplified not the actual way I write code. The `name can be simplified` message also would show up if you use the `namespaceX.class.functionname` in code already x namespace.

Comment: probably no difference in the code. best way to see would be to check the IL code of both versions.

Comment: You can suppress individual warnings on Visual Studio if it's really annoying you.

Comment: @TheAnathema Yea, I know, I just don't like doing that unless I am 100% sure that I don't care about the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any actual performance hit for not simplifying names or is the hit so small that I just don't see the difference because my program isn't big enough or some third option?

Not in the slightest.  This is just a style choice that has no impact on the compiled code.

I would pick a different name for your local variables, though.  Having the same name with just different casing on one letter makes it hard to distinguish between the local variable and the member name.

Answer (score 3):

There will not be a difference in the performance or memory footprint of the application. Your C# code is translated into IL by the compiler, and that is the code that is executed - since the compiler understands both the version with `this` and without, the resulting IL will be identical in both cases, and as such so will the performance of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can like or not qualifying class member access with `this`, but since in C# is avoidable and one of most important premises in programming is *keep as simple as possible*, while it's just a coding style issue, it's still interesting that you understand that **`this` in C# is used when you need to disambiguate an access to a local variable and a class member.**

There's no performance hit and it's just about that you get used with C# coding style. **For example, you use camel-casing on method identifiers while C# coding style says that they should be pascal-cased.**

Like any other convention and guideline, it's just there to make your code more predictable to others rather than to yourself (*and once you get used with these guidelines, they're also predictable for you too ;)*).

Answer (score 1):

BTW - the reason *not* to use `this` is because it makes you think that you dont need a naming convention for member variables.

Many people use a convention like

```
string _enddate
string endate_
string m_endate
```

that way you can tell by looking at the code that this is a member variable.

Using this.endate also says it is a member variable *but* the same code compiles if you just say enddate. Now you have code that compiles but you cannot tell at a glance if its a member or not